# I am getting Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException in my code when ever i try to store a new object in my array

Tags: java, exception

I am building an A* algorithm where i am suppose to add nodes to the grid[][] first ( in my case it is cells[i][j] ). So what i did is i run a loop in order to fill my 2D array with nodes with x and y coordinate filled inside it. But when ever i try to run my code it throws this exception `java.lang.NullPointerException`, i know this exception happens when object == null , but somehow i am not able to figure out the reason behind this problem, Here is my code :-

```
 private Node[][] cells;

 private void fill(){

    for(int i=0;i<rows;i++){
        for(int j=0 ; j<cols;j++){
            cells[i][j] = new Node(i,j,rows,cols); //throws exception this 
                                                     line
        }
    }
}
```

Please help me out to find the reason behind this.

Comment: Yes, you have `declared` but **not** specified how long the array will be.  Try `Node[][] cells = new Node[row][cell];`

Comment: @ScaryWombat yeah that was the problem , thank you so much :)

Comment: actually the problem is that the array(s) were not **initialized**, which is done by `new Node...` (the size must also be specified for that)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is because you are not initializaing cells array. Just inititalize it to proper size , then it should not be a problem. For example:

```
cells = new Node[5][5];
```

Comment: `cells = new Node[rows][cols];` precisely

Comment: oops, Thanks it is working now :)

Answer (score 0):

Just try `ArrayList<ArrayList<Node>>` if you don't know the size of array.

```
private ArrayList<ArrayList<Node>> nodes = new ArrayList<>();

for(int i=0;i<rows;i++){
       ArrayList<Node> n  = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int j=0 ; j<cols;j++){
           Node node =  new Node(i,j,rows,cols); //throws exception this 
                                                               line
           n.add(node )

        }
      nodes.add(n);
    }
```

If you know the size then use `Node[][] nodes = new Node[10][10]`.